# WebGL High GPU Usage

Tags: webgl

I am drawing thousand of colored quads by using WebGL (no any framework) and on my laptop, around 80k quads moves nicely in 60fps but more than 80K quads, fps starts waving regularly.  Like a few frame 30fp, one frame 60 fps. When i check it Chrome's performance tools, i noticed that GPU is taking too much time.

This is how Chrome Performance tool look like when i run 100k quads 
[image]

This is my example with no moving quads. Dynamic one also has same effect but STATIC one shows my problem better since no JS overhead.

My code here:

```js
var objects = [];
var MAX_COUNT = 10000;
var projectionMatrix;
var gl;
var positionVertexBuffer;
var colorVertexBuffer;
var indicesBuffer;

{

    gl = document.getElementById("renderCanvas").getContext("webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: false});
    gl.disable(gl.STENCIL_TEST);
    gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  
    document.getElementById("renderCanvas").onclick = createObjects;
    createObjects();
   requestAnimationFrame(updateScreen);
}


function createObjects () {

     projectionMatrix = new Float32Array([
        0.0033333333333333335,0,0,
        0,-0.0033333333333333335,0,
        0,0,1
    ]);
    
    var rObject = {};

    rObject.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
    createPrograms(rObject);

    createAttributes(rObject);

    createMoveObjects(rObject);

    rObject.id = "id_" + objects.length ;
    objects.push(rObject);
}

function createMoveObjects (outObject) {

    outObject.points = [];

    var k = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < MAX_COUNT; i++) {
          
        var x = (Math.random() * 600) - 300;
        var y = (Math.random() * 600) - 300;
        var vx =  (Math.random() * 10) - 5;
        var vy =  (Math.random() * 10) - 5;
        var size = 30 + Math.random() * 1;
        var w = 26 / 2;
        var h = 37 / 2;
        var p = {w:w, h:h, x:x, y:y, vx:vx, vy:vy, size:size};

        outObject.points.push(p);

      
    }
}



var shaderProgram;
function createPrograms(outObject) {

    var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, document.getElementById("vertexShader").textContent );
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

    if ( !gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ) {
        let finfo = gl.getShaderInfoLog( vertexShader );
        console.log("Vertex Shader Fail" , finfo);
    }

    var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, document.getElementById("fragmentShader").textContent);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

    if ( !gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ) {
        let finfo = gl.getShaderInfoLog( fragmentShader );
        console.log("Fragment Shader Fail" , finfo);
    }

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);

    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);


    

    var pmlocation = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,"projectionMatrix");
    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(pmlocation, false , outObject.projectionMatrix);
    outObject.projectionMatrixLocation = pmlocation;
    outObject.shaderProgram = shaderProgram;
}

function createAttributes(outObject) {
    

    var vertices = new Float32Array(MAX_COUNT * 8);
    var colors   = new Float32Array(MAX_COUNT * 12);
    var indices  = new Uint16Array(6 * MAX_COUNT);

    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i+=6) {        

        indices[i    ] = index;
        indices[i + 1] = index + 1;
        indices[i + 2] = index + 2;

        indices[i + 3] = index + 1;
        indices[i + 4] = index + 3;
        indices[i + 5] = index + 2;
        index += 4;
    }
    
    var r,g,b;

    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i+=12) {
        
        r = Math.random();
        g = Math.random();
        b = Math.random();

        colors[i] = r;
        colors[i + 1] = g;
        colors[i + 2] = b;


        colors[i + 3] = r;
        colors[i + 4] = g;
        colors[i + 5] = b;


        colors[i + 6] = r;
        colors[i + 7] = g;
        colors[i + 8] = b;


        colors[i + 9] = r;
        colors[i + 10] = g;
        colors[i + 11] = b;
    }
    

    var k = 0;
    var w = 26 / 2;
    var h = 37 / 2;
    var x,y;
   for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {

        x = (Math.random() * 600) - 300; 
        y = (Math.random() * 600) - 300; 
        vertices[k]     = -w + x; vertices[k + 1] =  h + y;
        vertices[k + 2] = -w + x; vertices[k + 3] = -h + y;
        vertices[k + 4] =  w + x; vertices[k + 5] =  h + y;
        vertices[k + 6] =  w + x; vertices[k + 7] = -h + y;
        k +=8;
   }

    positionVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionVertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    positionVertexBuffer.location = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"position");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionVertexBuffer.location,2 ,gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionVertexBuffer.location);
    
    colorVertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colorVertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colors, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    colorVertexBuffer.location = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,"color");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorVertexBuffer.location,3 ,gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorVertexBuffer.location);
    
    indicesBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);



    outObject.positionVertexBuffer = positionVertexBuffer;
    outObject.colorVertexBuffer = colorVertexBuffer;
    outObject.indicesBuffer = indicesBuffer;

    outObject.vertices = vertices;
    outObject.indices = indices;
    outObject.colors = colors;

    outObject.colorVertexLocation = colorVertexBuffer.location;
    outObject.positionVertexLocation = positionVertexBuffer.location;
}



function updateAllPoints() {

    var points;
    var p;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        
        points = objects[i].points;

        var k = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            
            p = points[j];

            p.x += p.vx;
            p.y += p.vy;

            if(p.x >= 300){
                p.x = 300;
                p.vx *= -1;
            } else if(p.x <= -300) {
                p.x = -300;
                p.vx *= -1;
            } else if(p.y >= 300){
                p.y = 300;
                p.vy *= -1;
            } else if(p.y <= -300) {
                p.y = -300;
                p.vy *= -1;
            }

            var vertices = objects[i].vertices;


            vertices[k]     = -p.w + p.x; vertices[k + 1] = p.h + p.y;
            vertices[k + 2] = -p.w + p.x; vertices[k + 3] = -p.h + p.y;
            vertices[k + 4] =  p.w + p.x; vertices[k + 5] = p.h + p.y;
            vertices[k + 6] =  p.w + p.x; vertices[k + 7] = -p.h + p.y;
            
            k +=8;
        }


    }


} 

function renderScene() {

  // updateAllPoints();

    var totalDraw = 0;
    gl.clearColor(0.3,0.3,0.3,1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    var rO;
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        
        rO = objects[i];
        
        drawObjects(rO);

          totalDraw += MAX_COUNT;
    }


    document.getElementById("objectCounter").innerHTML = totalDraw + " Objects"

}

function drawObjects (rO) {

    gl.useProgram(rO.shaderProgram);
   
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rO.positionVertexBuffer);
  //  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, rO.vertices);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(rO.positionVertexLocation,2 ,gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rO.colorVertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(rO.colorVertexLocation,3 ,gl.FLOAT, false, 0,0);
    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES,MAX_COUNT * 6 , gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

}




function updateScreen() {

    if(gl){

        renderScene();
        requestAnimationFrame(updateScreen);
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

    uniform mat3 projectionMatrix; 
    attribute vec2 position;
    attribute vec3 color;
    varying vec3 colorData;
    void main() {
        colorData = color;
        vec3 newPos = vec3(position.x, position.y, 1.0 ) * projectionMatrix;
        gl_Position = vec4(newPos , 1.0);
    }
    
</script>

<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision lowp float;
    uniform sampler2D uSampler;
    varying vec3 colorData;
    void main() { 
        gl_FragColor = vec4(colorData, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<canvas id="renderCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

<div id="objectCounter">10000 Objects</div>
<div>Evevy Click adds 10K Squares </div>
```

I also checked other examples and found PixiJS's [Bunnymark test](http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/bunnymark/) where you can run 120k bunnies in 60fps but no GPU overhead.

When comparing Bunnymark test, my GPU is taking too much time and I don't know why. I opimized it (of I think I did) but problem insists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it is because of i left antialias default as context attributes which seems "true". Can't believe i did not notice.

This code worked for me

```
canvasDom.getContext("webgl", {antialias : false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **scene.remove(mesh)** OR **mesh.parent.remove(mesh)**

Comment: This is a vanilla WebGL project. There is not ThreeJS or any other library in the code.